# Micronaut Lambda Native Image Not Reading Custom Handler

Tags: micronaut, graalvm-native-image, micronaut-aws

By default, Micronaut's handler is the class `MicronautLambdaHandler`. But on the Micronaut guide it says that

> The main API you will interact with is AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime. An abstract class which you can extend to create your custom runtime mainClass.

So I tried creating a custom handler and runtime, basically copying the existing `MicronautLambdaHandler` and `MicronautLambdaRuntime`

Custom MyRuntime

```
public class MyRuntime extends AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse, AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {

    @Override
    protected RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> createRequestHandler(String... args) {
        try {
            return new MyHandler(createApplicationContextBuilderWithArgs(args));
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            throw new ConfigurationException("Exception thrown instantiating MyHandler", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new MyRuntime().run(args);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Custom MyHandler that is just returning null

```
@Introspected
public class MyHandler implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse>,
        ApplicationContextProvider, Closeable {

    protected final MicronautLambdaContainerHandler handler;

    public MyHandler() throws ContainerInitializationException {
        this.handler = new MicronautLambdaContainerHandler();
    }

    public MyHandler(ApplicationContextBuilder applicationContextBuilder) throws ContainerInitializationException {
        this.handler = new MicronautLambdaContainerHandler(applicationContextBuilder);
    }

    public MyHandler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws ContainerInitializationException {
        this.handler = new MicronautLambdaContainerHandler(applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest input, Context context) {
        System.out.println("hello custom handler");
        System.out.println(context.getAwsRequestId());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return this.handler.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.getApplicationContext().close();
    }
}
```

Then on my Lambda Function I set the method handler to `example.micronaut.MyHandler` and the runtime to `Custom Runtime on Amazon Linux 2`

When testing my Lambda it doesn't read my custom handler. It always run the default `MicronautLambdaHandler`.

Also, what's weird is that even if I set the method handler to some random words like `this.is.not.a.handler`, it still run the `MicronautLambdaHandler` by default.

Is there a way to create my custom handler for Micronaut Lambda as Native Image as the guide suggests? Or I'm just really limited to using the default `MicronautLambdaHandler`?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to make it work.
I need to explicitly put the dependencies
`implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws")`
`implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws-custom-runtime")`

What I don't understand is that these artifacts already exist on the classpath even without specifying on build.gradle, that's why I never put them.

Comment: This works, but the `input.getRecords()` gives the empty messages (in case of `SQSEvent`). Any idea how we can retrieve the input message body?