# Micronaut with AWS Lambda and SQS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, micronaut, micronaut-aws

I have created simple application with Micronaut, and Graalvm and want to deploy it to the AWS Lambda and get it triggered from the SQS and process the messages. But somehow, it is not working as expected.

To build this application, I use command:
`gradlew buildNativeLambda`

Below is my setup:

**Micronaut application:**

**Trial 1: (not working)**

```
import com.example.services.TestService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class Controller {

    @Inject
    private TestService testService;

    @Post(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<String, Object> indexPost(@Body List<Map<String, Object>> requestBody) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return this.testService.handleRequest(requestBody.get(0));
    }
}
```

Prepare a build and upload it to Lambda and add the following handler: `io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaHandler`

**It just works fine when I try to trigger the lambda from "Test" tab on lambda management console**. However, when I add the SQS as trigger, and send the message to the SQS, the message does get disappeared from the queue (thus it is being read), but I see no logs in the lambda and the functionality is also not achieved. Thus it does not work with the SQS.

**Trial 2: (not working)**

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent;
import com.example.services.TestService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected;
import io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

import java.util.List;

@Introspected
public class SQSEventHandler extends MicronautRequestHandler<SQSEvent, Void> {

    @Inject
    private TestService testService;

    @Override
    public Void execute(SQSEvent input) {
        System.out.println("EVENT PROCESSING STARTS ===>");
        List<SQSEvent.SQSMessage> messages = input.getRecords();
        System.out.println("Number of messages:::" + messages.size());
        for (SQSEvent.SQSMessage single: messages) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Message body::: " + single.getBody());
                this.testService.handleRequest(single.getBody());
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("<=== EVENT PROCESSING ENDS");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Prepare a build and upload it to Lambda and add the following handler: `com.example.eventHandlers.SQSEventHandler`

Now it does the same behavior with the SQS message as previous one, the message gets disappeared from the queue, but no effect in lambda.

**Edit - 31-08-2022:**

I use below body as an event to test from "Test" tab in lambda console, and
this is to check the AWS Gateway event and **it does works fine** as we have `@Controller` class. Without `@Controller` it fails.

**Event data:**

```
{
  "path": "/",
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  "body": "<my req body>"
}
```

But when I try to test it with the SQS event, it fails. I have configured `com.example.eventHandlers.SQSEventHandler` as event handler in lambda for this test. Below is the event data which I used to test and the results:

**Event data**:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "059f36b4-87a3-44ab-83d2-661975830a7d",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBwJnKyrHigUMZj6rYigCgxlaS3SLy0a...",
            "body": "{\"action\": \"READ_ALL\"}",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1545082649183",
                "SenderId": "AIDAIENQZJOLO23YVJ4VO",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1545082649185"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "e4e68fb7bd0e697a0ae8f1bb342846b3",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:my-queue",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Results:**

```
{
  "statusCode": 405,
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "Allow": [
      "POST"
    ],
    "Content-Type": [
      "application/json"
    ]
  },
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Method Not Allowed\",\"_links\":{\"self\":{\"href\":\"https://nullnull\",\"templated\":false}},\"_embedded\":{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Method [GET] not allowed for URI [https://nullnull]. Allowed methods: [POST]\"}]}}",
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Comment: In your tests, shouldn't you try as the input json an SQSEvent instead of an API Gateway event?

Comment: Yes I already tried that. But get an error. Will update the results in the question.

Comment: When you created your project, did you use these options?
"mn create-function-app domain.my-app-name \
    --features=aws-lambda,graalvm \
    --build=gradle --lang=java"

did you use "create-app" or "create-function-app"?

I think if you used "create-app" the lambda must be invoked by Api Gateway

Comment: Yes @BrunoNegrãoZica, but I finally made it working. See my answer.

Comment: same issue with lambda admin role

Comment: What issue @JavaDude? Have you checked my answer below if that helps?

Comment: yeap, that works and help me. But looks like its MN bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally made it working, if anyone is looking for the solution:

**build.gradle:**

```
.
.
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java'
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compileOnly("org.graalvm.nativeimage:svm")
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws") <--- IMP!!!
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws-custom-runtime") <--- IMP!!!
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
}
.
.
```

**Application.java:** (The starting point of the application)

```
public class Application extends AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime<CustomSQSEvent, String, CustomSQSEvent, String> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
//        Micronaut.run(Application.class, args); // We don't need this now
        new Application().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    protected RequestHandler<CustomSQSEvent, String> createRequestHandler(String... args) {
        try {
            return new SQSEventHandler(createApplicationContextBuilderWithArgs(args));
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            throw new ConfigurationException("Exception thrown instantiating SQSEventHandler", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomSQSEvent.java:** (This is needed to handle the serialization/deserialization issues with the message. This is the exact copy of class `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent` with few annnotations.)

```
@Introspected <--- Very IMP!!!
public class CustomSQSEvent implements Serializable {
    
    @JsonProperty("Records") <--- Very IMP!!!
    private List<CustomSQSEvent.SQSMessage> records;
    
    @Introspected <--- Very IMP!!!
    public static class SQSMessage implements Serializable, Cloneable {
        ...
    }

     /**
     * Default constructor
     */
     public CustomSQSEvent() {
     }

     .
     .
     .

}
```

**SQSEventHandler.java:** (The actual magic happens here)

```
@Introspected
public class SQSEventHandler implements RequestHandler<CustomSQSEvent, String>, ApplicationContextProvider, Closeable {


    protected final MicronautLambdaContainerHandler handler;

    public SQSEventHandler() throws ContainerInitializationException {
        this.handler = new MicronautLambdaContainerHandler();
    }

    public SQSEventHandler(ApplicationContextBuilder applicationContextBuilder) throws ContainerInitializationException {
        this.handler = new MicronautLambdaContainerHandler(applicationContextBuilder);
    }

    public SQSEventHandler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws ContainerInitializationException {
        this.handler = new MicronautLambdaContainerHandler(applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(CustomSQSEvent input, Context context) {
        System.out.println("EVENT PROCESSING STARTS ===>");
        TestService testService = this.getApplicationContext().getBean(TestService.class);
        
        List<CustomSQSEvent.SQSMessage> messages = input.getRecords();

        for (CustomSQSEvent.SQSMessage single: messages) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Message body::: " + single.getBody());
                testService.handleRequest(single.getBody());
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("<=== EVENT PROCESSING ENDS");
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return this.handler.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.getApplicationContext().close();
    }
}
```

Removed `HomeController.java` (the class which has `@Controller`).

And finally build the project using following command: `gradlew buildNativeLambda -Pmicronaut.runtime=lambda`

Upload the created `zip` in the lambda and add the following as handler: `com.example.eventHandlers.SQSEventHandler`.
This is the path to our custom event handler.

Compiled solution from below references:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java.html
- https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/mn-serverless-function-aws-lambda-graalvm-gradle-java.html
- [Micronaut Lambda Native Image Not Reading Custom Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416766/micronaut-lambda-native-image-not-reading-custom-handler)
- https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/mn-serverless-function-aws-lambda-graalvm-gradle-java.zip

Comment: Hi Jignesh, thanks for posting. But creating a "CustomSQSEvent" sounds like a workaround, not a solution. Where did you take that idea from?

Comment: Yes agreed @BrunoNegrãoZica that is not a solution and a workaround. But as of now I cannot see any other solution. I tried created `ObjectMapper` bean but it didn't work, so ended up creating custom class. I got that idea from - https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-aws/issues/102#issuecomment-843571994

Comment: I created this issue https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-starter/issues/1383

Comment: Cool, that will be great to get some more reliable solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If your AWS Lambda function is not generating entries in Amazon CloudWatch Logs, then it normally indicates that the Lambda function has **insufficient permissions** to use CloudWatch Logs.

This can be fixed by **adding permissions to the IAM Role** associated with the Lambda function. Assign it the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy, which grants permission to write to CloudWatch Logs.

See: [AWS managed policies for Lambda features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html#permissions-executionrole-features)

Comment: Nope, permission is not the issue. It does generates the logs when triggered from "Test" tab. I have the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy assigned to the lambda function.

Comment: I do have this policy as well `AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole`

Comment: Are you sure that the AWS Lambda function is being triggered? Can you see it in the Invocations count in the Monitoring tab?

Comment: Yes, count is being incremented.

Comment: Okay, I can now see the logs (but not the one which I have printed in my method). Logs just contain the request ID. Don't know why previously logs were not printed in clouldwatch. I just changed the filter and they started appearing. But still the issue persists that lambda is not working as expected.

Comment: This does not seems to be related to AWS, it seems to be related to micronaut.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a project with micronaut to handle an SQSEvent. I got a lot of problems for read the SQS event in my function.
I used the https://micronaut.io/launch to generate my project with the next params:
Application Type: Function Application for Serverless
Micronaut Version: 3.9.3
Java Version: 17
Build Tool: Gradle
Test Framework: JUnit
Additional features: aws-lambda, graalvm
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNoYc.png

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")

implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.11.2")
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws")
implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws-custom-runtime")
implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc")

compileOnly("org.graalvm.nativeimage:svm")
runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
```

}

**FunctionLambdaRuntime.java**

```
public class FunctionLambdaRuntime extends AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime<SQSEvent, SQSBatchResponse, SQSEvent, SQSBatchResponse>{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new FunctionLambdaRuntime().run(args);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
@Nullable
protected RequestHandler<SQSEvent, SQSBatchResponse> createRequestHandler(String... args) {
    return new FunctionRequestHandler();
}
```

}

**FunctionRequestHandler.java**
Very important to add the Introspected annotation to the SQS necessary classes for the request and response!! You'll get a serialization error if you dont do this!

```
@Introspected(classes = {SQSEvent.class, SQSEvent.SQSMessage.class, SQSBatchResponse.class, SQSEvent.MessageAttribute.class, SQSBatchResponse.BatchItemFailure.class})
public class FunctionRequestHandler extends MicronautRequestHandler<SQSEvent, SQSBatchResponse> {
@Inject
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FunctionRequestHandler.class);

@Override
public SQSBatchResponse execute(SQSEvent input) {
    final List<SQSBatchResponse.BatchItemFailure> batchItemFailures = new ArrayList<>();
    final SQSBatchResponse response = new SQSBatchResponse(batchItemFailures);
    logger.info("SQS input: {}", input.toString());
    if(input == null){
        logger.error("SQSEvent input is null");
        return response;
    }
    logger.info("records {}", input.getRecords());

    for (SQSEvent.SQSMessage message : input.getRecords()) {
        try {
            MessagePaymentNotificationDto notification = this.objectMapper.readValue(message.getBody(), MessagePaymentNotificationDto.class);
            logger.info(notification.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            batchItemFailures.add(new SQSBatchResponse.BatchItemFailure(message.getMessageId()));
        }

    }
    return response;
}
```

}

Build the native image: *./gradlew buildNativeLambda -Pmicronaut.runtime=lambda* 
Upload the zip to your lambda function and configure com.example.eventHandlers.FunctionRequestHandler as handler.
In the **Test** tab of your lambda function go to the **Template** section and search for SQS and select it, it will configure a test json with the structure of an SQSEvent:
**Important:** When slected the SQS template the **"records"** attribute will be displayed as **"Records"**, change it to lowercase before send the test

```
{
  "records": [
{
  "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
  "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle",
  "body": "Hello from SQS!",
  "attributes": {
    "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
    "SentTimestamp": "1523232000000",
    "SenderId": "123456789012",
    "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001"
  },
  "messageAttributes": {},
  "md5OfBody": "{{{md5_of_body}}}",
  "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
  "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue",
  "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
}
]
}
```

Hope this help!